# Where does this 1 come from when balancing this integral equation?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$ \int e^{ax}\cos(bx)\,\mathrm dx = \frac1{a}e^{ax}\cos(bx) + \frac{b}{a^2}e^{ax}\sin(bx) - \frac{b^2}{a^2}\int e^{ax}\cos(bx)\,\mathrm dx$$

$$\left(1 + \frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)\int e^{ax}\cos(bx)\,\mathrm dx = \frac{1}{a}e^{ax}\cos(bx) + \frac{b}{a^2}e^{ax}\sin(bx) + C$$

Where does the $1$ in $\displaystyle \left(1 + \frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)$ come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah so they have taken the quantity $-b^{2}/a^{2}$ to the Left hand side. So you have the **LHS** as $$1 \cdot \int e^{ax}\cos(bx) \rm{dx} + \frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}} \int e^{ax}\cos(bx) \ \text{dx} = \Bigl(1+\frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}}\Bigr)\int e^{ax}\cos(bx) \ \text{dx}$$

Comment: If $a \neq 0$ and you multiply $a$ with $1$ you get $a$ itself.

Comment: I guess there is a 1 there. Thank you =)